# How do input more than one word for translation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a silly translator game as practice. I'm replacing "Ben" with "Idiot" but it only works when the only word I input is "Ben". If I input "Hello, Ben" then the console prints out a blank statement. I'm trying to get "Hello, Idiot". Or if I enter "Hi there, Ben!" I would want to get "Hi there Idiot!". If I input "Ben" then it converts to "Idiot" but only when the name by itself is entered.

I'm using Python 3 and am using function def translate(word): so maybe I'm over-complicating the process.

```
def translate(word):
translation = ""
if word == "Ben":
    translation = translation + "Idiot"

return translation


print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

I'm sorry if I explained all of this weird. Completely new to coding and using this website! Appreciate all of the help!

Comment: An answer is already given, so I just want to add that your current check only works if `Ben` is the only string input in the console. You might prefer `if "Ben" in word` if you want to check whether `Ben` is in the phrase input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

use `str.replace()` function for this:

```
sentence = "Hi there Ben!"
sentence=sentence.replace("Ben","Idiot")
Output: Hi there Idiot!
#str.replace() is case sensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you must split string to words:

```
s.split()
```

But that function, split string to words by `white spaces`, it's not good enough!

```
s = "Hello Ben!"
print(s.split())

Out: ["Hello", "Ben!"]
```

In this example, you can't find "Ben" easily.
We use `re` in this case:

```
re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', word)

Out: ["Hello", "Ben", ""]
```

But, we missed "!", We change it:

```
re.split('([^a-zA-Z])', word)

Out: ['Hello', ' ', 'Ben', '!', '']
```

and finally:

import re

```
def translate(word):
    words_list = re.split('([^a-zA-Z])', word)
    translation = ""
    for item in words_list:
        if item == "Ben":
            translation += "Idiot"
        else:
            translation += item

    return translation


print(translate("Hello Ben! Benchmark is ok!"))
```

## P.S:

If we use `replace`, we have a wrong answer!

```
"Hello Ben! Benchmark is ok!".replace("Ben", "Idiot")

Out: Hello Idiot! Idiotchmark is ok!
```